# Type anywhere in activity to open a edittext view in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

When a user starts writing on a hardware keyboard I need the activity to direct that input to a certain edittext view.

I've tried to "hard code" it by overriding key events, but that is very inefficient. Especially when it comes to supporting various countries and languages..

Example:

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B:
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C:
etc.
```

Is there any way of doing this simple and clean in Android?
As a reference, Google Play Store has that same feature I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to setFocus() when any key is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.

```
@Override   
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

    final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    if (!mEditText.hasFocus()){ 
        mEditText.requestFocus();
        mEditText.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this approach but It doesn't seem to work. I'll try more with this method tomorrow. I'll keep you updated if I get it working.  Thanks